# Problem in conversion from number to char

Tags: .net, vb.net

Hi i want to convert following number to character equivalent but without using any special character. Please Help me. Thank you very much

32545352515049515448524848495270484848484870706670666970

Comment: How do you mean character equivalent? Can you post your current code?

Comment: What is type of variable that is holding this number?

Comment: I mean If first number is 3 then i want C i used ASCII but it is showing special character

Comment: Thank you, Actually With your Solution I added 69 Because 64 is giving @ at number 3 thank you very much again

Comment: ASCII representation of 64 is @, 65 is A, 66 is B,... . I don't quit understand why you would have to use 69. 69+3 = 72 = H.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 64 ($40) to each number before converting it to a character.

Uppercase characters start at 65 ($41) in the [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) table.

Comment: Just to add that lower case letter start at 97 ($61).